# How can I find a printer driver for the EPSON WF-C4810?

Tags: 22.04, printing

I can't print to my Epson WF-C4810. It works from Windows so I assume I need to find the right driver. Is one available?

Comment: Printers are supposed to be detected automatically and work without any additional drivers in Ubuntu 22.04. Please explain if it does not work.

Comment: @User68186 Sadly it isn't working. It's on my LAN and it seems to detect something is happening when I try to print but it doesn't actually print.